# Skipped xx-frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android

I'm quite new to android, however i tried making some simple apps.
    But this one is getting worse for me. i searched a lot, they say that we should use "Asynch" method or use "new runnable method", but still not getting the exact solution.
    Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.mit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.addition:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this,Addition.class);
            startActivityForResult(i1, 500);

            break;
        case R.id.overlap:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Overlap.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        case R.id.bcd:
            Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Bcd.class);
            startActivity(i3);
            break;
        case R.id.string1:
            Intent i4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,String1.class);
            startActivity(i4);
            break;
        case R.id.string2:
            Intent i5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,String2.class);
            startActivity(i5);
            break;
        case R.id.mul:
            Intent i6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Mul.class);
            startActivity(i6);
            break;
        case R.id.mean:
            Intent i7 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Mean.class);
            startActivity(i7);
            break;
        }   
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple code and you're probably getting that warning because you're using an emulator. If that is the case, then it is normal because emulators are not as fast as real android devices. You don't need to use AsyncTask or Runnable for this.

Comment: Adding my two cents, you might want to apply a log filter as well!